# Why does octal dump output the ascii code for an integer variable instead of the binary code?

Tags: c, linux, file

This is the code in C to input a character and integer variable to a file.

```
int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp;
    char file[20];
    int i = 40;

    printf("Enter filename: ");
    scanf("%s", file);

    fp = fopen(file, "wb");

    fprintf(fp, "%d", i);
    fprintf(fp, "%c%c", '4', '0');

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

So lets say the file name is text and the od command is invoked..

```
od -xc text
```

This is the output of the command

```
0000000    3034    3034
            4 0     4 0
```

Why does it print the ASCII values for both of the value 40 and not the hex code 0028 for the integer variable?

Comment: Because the strings are written in ASCII?

Comment: Perhaps you better read the `od` manual?

Comment: You didn't write the actual bytes making up the integer... you wrote a string containing a text representation of the number in the integer, produced by `fprintf()`... so that's what you get when you view it.

Comment: I still can't see how the code shown can generate the output shown. Neither to console, nor to the file. Either you show only part of the output and program or you have another problem. As you don't chekc the results for `scanf` and `fopen`. Read [ask]. And there is no hex conversion specifier shown, so why do you think to get hex-codes?

Comment: Use something like `fprintf(fp, "%c%c", (i>>8)&255, (i>>0)&255);` or even better `fwrite()`.

Comment: @Olaf `-x` option for `od` gives two-byte units as hexadecimal

Comment: @Dmitri: My fault. I didn't know about the `od` command, but thought that was OPs original program. Anyway, if the first row is the hex-codes for the data and the 2nd row the ASCII-codes, the output is still confusing, as the bytes seem to be swapped, but the ASCII-chars are not. That leave the quesdtion to being badly researched. OP just should read the man-page of `(f)printf`

Comment: @Olaf I do not know why the bytes are swapped but that is exactly how my command line showed the output.

Comment: @Patrick: I did not doubt **that** (once I checked the `od` command). It is just that you apparently did not even a bit of research what `printf` actually does. I can understand (still not accept) this for less common functions, but not for something every C book uses almost from the beginning. Please next time do at least some research (this is a requirement before asking and a valid reason to DV, btw.)

Comment: @Olaf Alright! My bad. What do you mean by DV btw?

Comment: @Patrick downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fprintf` formats all output *as text* - `fprintf( fp, "%d", 42 )` writes the character values `'4'` and `'2'` to the output stream, same as `fprintf( fp, "%c%c", '4', '2' )` and `fprintf( fp, "%s", "42" )`.

If you want to write the binary representation of the integer to your output stream, then you need to use `fwrite( &i, sizeof i, 1, fp );`.